# Generic parameter will be decided by a getter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there a way to do something like that:

```
public interface ISomething {
        Type e { get; }
        Expression<Func<e, long>> GetExpression(); //COMPILE ERROR
}
```

I get the compile error: e is property but using like a type.

I want the Generic parameter will be decided by a getter - is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "generic parameter will be decided by a getter"?

Comment: @BoltClock: In the example above, Expression<Func<e, long>> GetExpression(); marked with compile error.

Comment: You'll have to use reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, though I don't quite understand the purpose of the `e` property.

```
public interface ISomething<T> 
{
    T SomeProperty { get; }
    Expression<Func<T, long>> GetExpression();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the Generic in "public interface ISomething<T>" ?  the e property should define the generic type.

Comment: @Naor: No, there isn't. Generic types are determined at compile time, not at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep `ISomething` non-generic then you can make only `GetExpression` generic:

```
public interface ISomething 
{
     Expression<Func<T, long>> GetExpression<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public interface ISomething<T> {
 {
         Expression<Func<T, long>> GetExpression();
 }
```

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the Generic in "public interface ISomething<T>" ?